# When using jqgrid in asp.net-mvc site, is there a way to include the filter in the url so you can share filtered views?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid, query-string

I have an asp.net-mvc site and I user [jqgrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/) on the front end. I have a simple page using jqgrid and I filter down my jqgrid results (server side filter) using the top bar filter of the advanced filter.

I now want a way where I can share a URL with someone else and when they load the page, they get the same filter applied so somehow I need to take the filter criteria and append it to the query string.

The issue is that I can do this "manually" field by field like this by creating queryparams like

```
 myurl?NameFilter=JoeBrown
```

and then doing something like this in my asp.net-mvc view

```
 var myfilter = { groupOp: "AND", rules: [] };

 <% if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.NameFilter)) { %>
     myfilter.rules.push({ field: "Name", op: "eq", data: "<% = Model.NameFilter%>" });
<%}%>
```

but that doesn't really scale very well given I have many different pages with lots of columns so I am looking for a more generic way to persist the filter values into a URL and then apply them again so that I can then model bind on the server side back to my controller action.

Here is an example Server Side controller action that I am calling to load data from the server:

```
public ActionResult GridData(GridData args)
{
  var data = GetData(args).Paginate(args.page ?? 1, args.rows ?? 10,
                                                      i =>
                                                          new
                                                      {
                                                          i.Id,
                                                          i.Name
                                                      }
   }
```

so basically I need the query string to bind to my **GridData** class similar to what happens when I do a normal filter that gets posted on the ajax call when I do a regular filter.

My **GridData** class looks like this:

```
public class GridData
{
    public int? page { get; set; }
    public int? rows { get; set; }
    public bool search { get; set; }
    public string sidx { get; set; }
    public string sord { get; set; }
    public Filter Where { get; set; }
}

public class Filter
{
    public string groupOp { get; set; }
    public Rule[] rules { get; set; }
}

public class Rule
{
    public string field { get; set; }
    public string op { get; set; }
    public string data { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Would it be feasible to simply serialize the query object into the db and associate a key with it? Then have a share button on your site that presents the user with a tiny-url-like-url with the key embedded. They then share that and when the receiving user hits the url, your app does a db lookup, deserializes the query and replays it. Note using this method you could also enforce user created permissions.

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking for a way to construct a model that will bind directly from query string values, you can try the following. The methods buildParamsCustom() and serializeJson() are basically taken from jQuery source and modified for creating a query string which will be supported by the MVC default model binder.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/ has the details about the default jQuery implementation.

I have tested for your scenario. I am able to view the serialized data.

```
var r20 = /%20/g, rbracket = /\[\]$/;

function buildParamsCustom(prefix, obj, traditional, add) {
    var name;

    if (jQuery.isArray(obj)) {
        // Serialize array item.
        jQuery.each(obj, function (i, v) {
            if (traditional || rbracket.test(prefix)) {
                // Treat each array item as a scalar.
                add(prefix, v);

            } else {
                // Item is non-scalar (array or object), encode its numeric index.
                buildParamsCustom(prefix + "[" + (typeof v === "object" ? i : "") + "]", v, traditional, add);
            }
        });

    } else if (!traditional && jQuery.type(obj) === "object") {
        // Serialize object item.
        for (name in obj) {
            buildParamsCustom(prefix + "." + name, obj[name], traditional, add);
        }

    } else {
        // Serialize scalar item.
        add(prefix, obj);
    }
}

// Serialize an array of form elements or a set of
// key/values into a query string
var serializeJson = function (a, traditional) {
    var prefix,
        s = [],
        add = function (key, value) {
            // If value is a function, invoke it and return its value
            value = jQuery.isFunction(value) ? value() : (value == null ? "" : value);
            s[s.length] = encodeURIComponent(key) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(value);
        };

    // Set traditional to true for jQuery <= 1.3.2 behavior.
    if (traditional === undefined) {
        traditional = jQuery.ajaxSettings && jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional;
    }

    // If an array was passed in, assume that it is an array of form elements.
    if (jQuery.isArray(a) || (a.jquery && !jQuery.isPlainObject(a))) {
        // Serialize the form elements
        jQuery.each(a, function () {
            add(this.name, this.value);
        });

    } else {
        // If traditional, encode the "old" way (the way 1.3.2 or older
        // did it), otherwise encode params recursively.
        for (prefix in a) {
            buildParamsCustom(prefix, a[prefix], traditional, add);
        }
    }

    // Return the resulting serialization
    return s.join("&").replace(r20, "+");
};
// Get this data from the grid
var data = { "page": 1, "rows": 10, "search": true, "Where": { "groupop": "AND", "rules": [{ "field": "Name", "op": "EQ", data: "John" }, { "field": "Title", "op": "EQ", data: "Mr" }] } };
var queryString = serializeJson(data);    
var url = "someurl" + "?" + decodeURIComponent(queryString);
// Send your GET request here.
```

Comment: but how do i get the data from the jqgrid?